# Migrating from localStorage to chrome.storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-storage

I'm in the process of migrating my Chrome extension's persistency repository, from localStorage to chrome.storage. An important difference between them is that chrome.storage is asynchronous, therefore a callback function needs to be passed.

How would you modify a loop that writes to localStorage, synchronously, to the async chrome.storage?

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem(obj[i].key, obj[i].val);
}
doThisWhenAllElementsAreSaved();
```

Thanks.

Comment: You probably will end with _deffered_ conception. Good article is [here](http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics). It's about jQuery, but main algorith does not require any library. Otherwise you can just create array of flags (complete: true/false) or counter of called callbacks and check in any callbacks if ALL of it true or completed count == total count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, I'll use `chrome.storage.local`, but you can replace it with `chrome.storage.sync` if you prefer.

The goal is to use [`chrome.storage.local.set`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-set). The first step is to convert your `obj` into an object that contains the list of pair of key / value:

```js
var keyValue = {};
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) 
{
    keyValue[obj[i].key] = obj[i].val;
}
```

Then we call the actual method:

```js
chrome.storage.local.set(keyValue, function()
{     
   // Notify that we saved.
   doThisWhenAllElementsAreSaved();
});
```

or, simply:

```js
chrome.storage.local(keyValue, doThisWhenAllElementsAreSaved);
```

Note that the callback will be called on success, as well as on failure. If the storage failed, then `chrome.runtime.lastError` will be set.

Answer (score 1):

You can save multiple items at once with the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API, so I would use the following approach:

#### Before, using `localStorage.setItem`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem(obj[i].key, obj[i].val);
}
doThisWhenAllElementsAreSaved();
```

#### After, using [`chrome.storage.local.set`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-set)

```js
var items = {};
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    items[obj[i].key] = obj[i].val;
}
chrome.storage.local.set(items, function() {
    doThisWhenAllElementsAreSaved();
});
```

If you need to know whether the save operation succeeded, check the value of [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError) in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be just to change the code to use `chrome.storage.local` like others said.

But sometimes, it gets really messy and you may want some code to remain untouched.

I tried to use a library that highly incorporates `window.localStorage` in a packaged app environment(the library was angular-cached-resource) and didn't want to change the original source code. So I managed to make the following shim: https://github.com/stewartpark/chrome-localStorage-shim

Hope it helps! Happy hacking.